# functions are not valid as a react child, why am I getting this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children, react-props

I am getting this issue whereby I have this component

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {
    myFunc() {

    }

    myFunc2(){

    }
    render this.myFunc() ? (
        <div> 
            { this.myFunc2() ? (
                <AnotherComponent />
            ) : <Fragment />
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

but I am getting the error: `functions are not valid as a react child` for when I try to render `func2` in the render block?

however, when I assign it to a `const` like `const x = this.myFunc2()` and then render `x ? something : null` instead. the error goes away

both `myFunc` and `myFunc2` are just returning true or false based on props so why am I getting this error?

and why do I get the error for `myFunc2` but not `myFunc`?

Comment: return value from func2 of boolean type for ternary operator to work..Right now your func2 is returning undefined.

Comment: think it's to do with styled components :/

Comment: This is not valid syntax. `render` should be a method.

Comment: This code in syntactically invalid, not sure what is going on with your render method

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to make `render` a function like

`render()`

Secondly, your render function needs to return a value:

`render() { return ....}`

And lastly, you need to complete the ternary operator for `this.myFunc()` condition check

`this.myFunc() ? .... : null`

Here's a working example for the same:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sdpbgg?file=Hello.js